# Functions or loop are not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

So having problems with both methods. Method (this.howMuch) is supposed to calculate the distance given car went (based on speed and time inputs). Method (this.printAll) is supposed to print all information about objects that are in the array. The only error i see is that "carConstruct.howMuch is not a function at HTMLButtonElement". Same error for the second method if i delete the first one.

All help appreciated. Code below:

```js
var vardas = document.getElementById("name");
var laikas = document.getElementById("time");
var greitis = document.getElementById("speed");
var driver = document.getElementById("driver");
var addCar = document.getElementById("addCar");
var race = document.getElementById("race");
var box = document.getElementById("box");
var cars = [];

function carConstruct(name, time, speed, driver, distance){
    this.name = name;
    this.time = time;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.driver = driver;
    this.distance = 0;
    this.howMuch = function(){
        for(var i=0; i<cars[i]["time"]; i++){
            this.distance = this.distance + (cars[i]["speed"] * cars[i]["time"]);
        }
    }
    this.printAll = function(){
        for(var i=0; i<cars.length; i++){
        console.log(cars[i]["name"]);
        console.log(cars[i]["speed"]);
        console.log(cars[i]["driver"]);
        console.log(cars[i]["distance"]);
        }
    }
}

addCar.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var carNew = new carConstruct(vardas.value, laikas.value, greitis.value, driver.value);
    cars.push(carNew);
    vardas.value = "";
    greitis.value = "";
    driver.value = "";
});

race.addEventListener("click", function(){
    carConstruct.howMuch();
    carConstruct.printAll();
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>J21ND</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="J21ND.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="fields">
            <h1>Car Race</h1>
            <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Input car name">
            <input id="time" type="number" placeholder="Input car time">
            <input id="speed" type="number" placeholder="Input car speed">
            <input id="driver" type="text" placeholder="Input driver level, select: Rookie or Pro">
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button id="addCar">Add Car</button>
            <button id="race">Start Race</button>
        </div>
        <div id="box">
        </div>
        <script src="J21ND.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Right, your constructor function is not an instance of an object it creates, so it doesn't have those instance methods. Those should just be standalone functions that operate on the `cars` array.

Comment: `howMuch()` would be a method available on `carNew`, not `carConstruct`

Answer (score 2):

You could do it by simply adding a global flag. Here is the customized code.

```
// Above code will remain same in js and HTML code will remain same as well
    var flag =0;    
    addCar.addEventListener("click", function(){
            var carNew = new carConstruct(vardas.value, laikas.value, greitis.value, driver.value);
            cars.push(carNew);
            flag=1;
            vardas.value = "";
            greitis.value = "";
            driver.value = "";
        });

        race.addEventListener("click", function(){
            if(flag!=0){
               var addedCar = cars.pop()
               addedCar.howMuch();
               addedCar.printAll();
               flag =0;
            }else{
               alert('Please Add Car First');
               flag =0;
            }
        });
```